# "No such table" Error using an existing database in Android 9 and below

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use an existing SQLite database in Android Studio. It works in Android 10+ but in Android 9 and below I get this error:

> No such table

`DatabaseHelper` class:

```
package com.example.testlocaldatabase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Build;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static String DB_NAME = "myDatabase.SqLite";
  private static String DB_PATH = "";
  private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private Context context;
  private boolean needUpdate = false;

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
      DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

    } else {
      DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.context = context;
    copyDatabase();
    this.getReadableDatabase();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    if (i1 > i) {
      needUpdate = true;
    }

  }

  private void copyDatabase() {

    if (!checkDatabase()) {
      this.getReadableDatabase();
      this.close();
      try {
        copyDBFile();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database");
      }//catch
    }//if
  }//copyDatabase

  private boolean checkDatabase() {
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    if (dbFile.exists()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private void copyDBFile() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
  }

  public void updateDatabase() throws IOException {
    if (needUpdate) {
      File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
      if (dbFile.exists())
        dbFile.delete();
      copyDatabase();
      needUpdate = false;

    }//if
  }//updateDatabase

  @Override
  public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
      database.close();
    }
    super.close();

  }
}
```

`MainActivity` :

```
package com.example.testlocaldatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
  private SQLiteDatabase database;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
    try {
      databaseHelper.updateDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    database = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    // pull out data from database
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select * from drugs", null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
      String b = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("drugName"));
      Log.i("LOG", "" + b);
    }
    cursor.close();

  }

}
```

Error line in logcat :

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: drugs (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from drugs

Comment: You should update the Database Version in your DatabaseHelper....like..... private static int DB_VERSION = 2;

Comment: thanks it works , but what happened ? i hadn't install the app on this device before. why do i need to update the DB_VERSION ? and why it worked on android 10+ but didn't in android 9 and less ?

Comment: Not sure about the First Time installation, but after android 10 Storage policy has got changed. in android 13 every time you need to update the database version when you have done any changes in DB schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On android 13 every time you need to update the database version when you have done any changes in DB schema.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static String DB_NAME = "myDatabase.SqLite";
  private static String DB_PATH = "";
  private static int DB_VERSION = 2;


  private SQLiteDatabase database;
  private Context context;
  private boolean needUpdate = false;

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
      DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

    } else {
      DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    this.context = context;
    copyDatabase();
    this.getReadableDatabase();
  }
```